# Pick an easter egg for chat.superuser!

Tags: discussion, chat

On chat.meta.stackoverflow, there's a little easter egg where text entered as

> [status-blah]

will be rendered as a moderator only tag.

We'd like to do something similar, but specific to superuser -- namely, **when you type a magic string, something amusing and in-joke-y for *superuser.com* happens**, and it's visible to the entire chat room.

Do you have any ideas for anything super-user-y we can do as an easter egg in chat.superuser.com ?

Answer here, or in the dedicated chat room for this topic at http://chat.superuser.com/rooms/14/pick-a-meme

Comment: Someone yesterday mentioned something involving Microsoft Clippy - Would love to see that!... can't really suggest much past that!

Comment: You should work on that accept rate ;)

Answer (score 13):

via [@balpha](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/7326):

> how about this: When the message matches /^how (?:can|do) I (.+)\?/i, a talking paper clip appears with a speech bubble saying "It looks like you're trying to \1. Do you want some help?" and a link to SU

ala

[image]

from:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/11/dont-forget-to-lock-your-computer.html

Comment: I encountered this today and I was horrified.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, As was I, just now....

Answer (score 5):

How about involving the term

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?

.. for random questions? Not sure if it would work, but that quote solves about 90% of the questions right? :-)
(perhaps it would fit better on [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com) though)

Comment: @Michael, good news, you can [propose it](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/818/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-serverfault)

Comment: @Lord: sweet! I'll propose it there as well :)

Comment: Seemed to work fine, couldn't reassociate with one account, but I'll retry some day. here's the new [response](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/818/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-serverfault/835#835) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to ensure the discussions on chat are not lost.

via @Ivo Links: [1](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/9786), [2](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/9789), [3](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/9790), [4](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/9793)

> yeah it's pretty universal.
>   Anyone who dares press the send button in the interface
>   should get an error with [this comic](http://geeksaresexy.geeksaresexytech.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/computeruse2.gif)

Comment: I saw that on Reddit today...not as funny as [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/5321/whats-the-weirdest-thing-youve-ever-seen-a-non-techie-do-to-a-computing-device).

Answer (score -1):

via [@JNK](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/7119)

> AIt would be funny if anytime anyone said recursion it linked to the google search for recursion, which is in itself hilarious

Comment: I would repeat the message if someone said recursion

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who wants a lame one: 
!!!! -> Crazy seizure-inducing banner ad.

Answer (score -1):

How about something I am using in subversion comments for a long time:

> Bunny appreciates this code
>   (\ /)
>   (O.o)
>   (> <)
>   Don´t mess with bunny!

It is editable so bunny can appreciate everything you do ;-)

Comment: BUNNIEZZ ARE EVIL!!!!!!!!!!!